# Problem with compostion and access to nested objects

Tags: python, composition

So i have a parent class lets call it A

Inside of object A there are sub objects (not inheritance) these are compositional objects called B and C lets say.

So something like this

```
    class A(object):
    def __init__():
    B = B()
    C= C()
    
    
    
class B():
    def __init__(self):
    self.attribute_1 = whatever
    
class C():
    def __init__(self):
    self.attribute_1 = whatever


Parent_object = A()
```

No the problem comes in

I have a method inside of object B that object C needs access to

How do i do that?

I have tried various different versions of self and it wont compile (interpret)
Like this

```
class A(object):
    def __init__():
    B = B()
    C= C()
    
    
    
class B():
    def __init__(self):
    self.attribute_1 = whatever
    
    
class C():
    def __init__(self):
    self.attribute_1 = whatever
    
    #This wont work
    self.new_thing = self.b.attribute_1


Parent_object = A()
```

How do i make this work? In other words, the two sub objects need access to each others stuff.

Thanks

Comment: You can get access to variables and methods of another class inside the child class via inheritance. You can then use the super() method or use getters. I can infer from your code that you have little knowledge about object-oriented programming in python, please look up concepts of inheritance and nested class. I am sure there must be a more efficient way for whatever you are trying to achieve.

Comment: No, this is not inheritance You absolutely do not want inheritance in this case. There is a reason its done with composition.  Inheritance in python is a disaster and so is the super function. Its also pretty funny that you think because i gave a few lines of example code i wrote in 10 seconds on a notepad you can infer anything about me. that is rather funny

Comment: _" Inheritance in python is a disaster and so is the super function"_ why? do you have to deal with diamonds inheritance?

Answer (score 0):

I believe this answers the question, although I may have misinterpreted what exactly it is you're asking, anyway I used getters and parsed the parent class into B and C

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = B(self)
        self.c = C(self)

    def get_B(self):
        return self.b
    
class B():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.attribute_1 = "whatever1"
        self.parent = parent

    def get_attribute_1(self):
        return self.attribute_1
    
    
class C():
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.attribute_1 = "whatever2"
        self.new_thing = self.parent.get_B().get_attribute_1()
        print(self.new_thing)

Parent_object = A()
```

Comment: I mean, there has got to be a better way. That is clear as mud. It will work and if you had one or two things to handle then ok, but when you have a class with a lot of objects you this is not feasible. There has to be a better way with the almighty python.